# go - Attribute in a tag/hide parent tag: SOAP envelope

Tags: xml, go, soap

I'm trying to encode Go struct into a Soap-Envelope (xml).
So far, the soap body looks fine except one small error.
While my envelope should look like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <q3:WMLS_AddToStore xmlns:q3="http://www.foo.abr/message/120">
        <WMLtypeIn>param1</WMLtypeIn>
        <XMLin>param2</XMLin>
        <OptionsIn>param3</OptionsIn>
        <CapabilitiesIn>param4</CapabilitiesIn>
    </q3:WMLS_AddToStore>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

My code is Generating this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <q1:WMLS_AddToStore xmlns:q1="http://www.foo.abr/message/120">
    <ActionName>
      <WMLtypeIn>param1</WMLtypeIn>
      <XMLin>param2</XMLin>
      <OptionsIn>param3</OptionsIn>
      <CapabilitiesIn>param4</CapabilitiesIn>
    </ActionName>
  </q1:WMLS_AddToStore>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Notice the ActionName tag. I want to either:

Remove this ActionName tag

OR

Rename it to `q3:WMLS_AddToStore`(which I can do) but then I need to add the `xmlns:q1` attribute to it.

CODE:

```
type Message interface{}
type OperationWMLS_AddToStoreSoapIn struct {
WMLtypeIn      string `xml:"WMLtypeIn,omitempty"`
XMLin          string `xml:"XMLin,omitempty"`
OptionsIn      string `xml:"OptionsIn,omitempty"`
CapabilitiesIn string `xml:"CapabilitiesIn,omitempty"`
}

type Body struct {
XMLName    xml.Name     `xml:"SOAP-ENV:Body"`
ActionName temperature `xml:"q1:WMLS_AddToStore"`
}

type Action struct {
ActionName Message `xml:",innerxml"`
XMLAttr    string  `xml:"xmlns:q1,attr"`
}

func main() {
in := struct {
    OperationWMLS_AddToStoreSoapIn `xml:"tns:WMLS_AddToStore"`
}{
    OperationWMLS_AddToStoreSoapIn{
        "WMLtypeIn",
        "XMLin",
        "OptionsIn",
        "CapabilitiesIn",
    },
}

x := &Body{
    ActionName: Action{
        ActionName: in,
        XMLAttr: "http://www.foo.abr/message/120",
        },
    }

enc := xml.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)
enc.Indent("", "  ")
if err := enc.Encode(x); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
}

}
```

Here's the playground:
https://play.golang.org/p/fWl-G2d8ME2

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.*

Comment: Adrian, The playground code is working. I just need to get rid of the ActionName tag. I'll add the code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you think of rewriting your code like that (https://play.golang.org/p/Kf5VpQeuThx) :

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

type s2 struct {
    XMLName        xml.Name `xml:"q3:WMLS_AddToStore"`
    XMLAttr        string   `xml:"xmlns:q3,attr"`
    WMLtypeIn      string   `xml:"WMLtypeIn,omitempty" json:"WMLtypeIn,omitempty" yaml:"WMLtypeIn,omitempty"`
    XMLin          string   `xml:"XMLin,omitempty" json:"XMLin,omitempty" yaml:"XMLin,omitempty"`
    OptionsIn      string   `xml:"OptionsIn,omitempty" json:"OptionsIn,omitempty" yaml:"OptionsIn,omitempty"`
    CapabilitiesIn string   `xml:"CapabilitiesIn,omitempty" json:"CapabilitiesIn,omitempty" yaml:"CapabilitiesIn,omitempty"`
}

type s1 struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"SOAP-ENV:Body"`
    S2      s2
}

func main() {
    x := &s1{
        S2: s2{
            XMLAttr:        "http://www.foo.abr/message/120",
            WMLtypeIn:      "WMLtypeIn",
            XMLin:          "XMLin",
            OptionsIn:      "OptionsIn",
            CapabilitiesIn: "CapabilitiesIn",
        },
    }

    enc := xml.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)
    enc.Indent("", "  ")
    if err := enc.Encode(x); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this works. This is what I did. However, it would have been better not to change the OperationWMLS_AddToStoreSoapIn struct.